# how do i navigate between multiple screens and i get the following error(undefined is not an object(this.props.navigation))

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

[image]i'm new to react-native and mobile application. I'm trying to build a basic shopping app.i have the sports options such as cricket,football,tennis and whenever the tennis button is pressed, the tennis products will be displayed and there is a buy option which when clicked will lead to the payment page but i"m not able to navigate between my second screen to third screen and i get the following error

(undefined is not an object(this.props.navigation))

i tried using props for the overall function but it doesnt work

1.app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text,  View } from 'react-native';


import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react- 
navigation'
import FirstScreen from './src/FirstScreen'
import SecondScreen from './src/cricket'
import ThirdScreen from './src/football'
import FourthScreen from './src/tennis'
import FifthScreen from './src/paymentdetails'

 const Navigation = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
 First: {screen: FirstScreen},
 Second: {screen: SecondScreen},
 Third: {screen: ThirdScreen},
 Fourth: {screen: FourthScreen},
 Fifth: {screen: FifthScreen}


 }));

 export default Navigation
```

2.FirstScreen.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Alert, AppRegistry, Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, 
 TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, TouchableNativeFeedback, 
 TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from 'react-native';
 import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
 export default class FirstScreen extends Component {
 //_onPressButton() {
 // Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')
 //}
constructor(props){
super(props)
this._onPressButton1.bind(this)
this._onPressButton2.bind(this)
this._onPressButton3.bind(this)
}

_onPressButton1=()=>{
this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
}
_onPressButton2=()=>{
this.props.navigation.navigate("Third")
}
_onPressButton3=()=>{
this.props.navigation.navigate("Fourth")
}



static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'First Screen',
};


render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton1}>

     <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Cricket</Text>
        <Image
        //We are showing the Image from online
        source={{
          uri:
            'http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Cricket-Transparent- 
 Background.png',
        }}
        //You can also show the image from you project directory like 
 below
        //source={require('./Images/facebook.png')}
        //Image Style
        style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
      />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton2}>

     <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Football</Text>
        <Image
        //We are showing the Image from online
        source={{
          uri:
            'http://pngimg.com/uploads/football/football_PNG52793.png',
        }}
        //You can also show the image from you project directory like 
 below
        //source={require('./Images/facebook.png')}
        //Image Style
        style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
      />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton3}>

     <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Tennis</Text>
        <Image
        //We are showing the Image from online
        source={{
          uri:
            'http://pngimg.com/uploads/tennis/tennis_PNG10421.png',
        }}
         //You can also show the image from you project directory like 
   below
        //source={require('./Images/facebook.png')}
        //Image Style
        style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
      />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
    );
   }
    }
```

3.tennis.js

```
class Greeting extends Component {

  constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this._onPressButton.bind(this)
   }

 _onPressButton=()=>{
   this.props.navigation.navigate("Fifth")
  }



  static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'Fourth Screen',
  };


  render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        title="BUY"
      />
    </View>
  </View>
  );

  }
  }

  export default class FourthScreen extends Component {



  render() {
  return (
  <ScrollView>
  <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', top: 0, flex: 2, 
  backgroundColor: 'black'}}>

    <Greeting name='Shoe- 800' />
    <Greeting name='Jersey - 350' />
    <Greeting name='Stockings - 100' />
    <Greeting name='Cones - 50' />
    <Greeting name='Whistle - 80' />
    <Greeting name='Rackets - 7000' />
    <Greeting name='Tennis Ball-6 pack - 800' />
    <Greeting name='Nets - 1500' />

  </View>
  </ScrollView>
  );
  }
  }
```

4.paymentdetails.js

```
export default class FifthScreen extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Fifth Screen',
};

_onPressButton() {
Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')
}

render() {
return (


    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.alternativeLayout }>
    <Text>Payment Gateway</Text>
    </View>
    <RadioForm
      radio_props={hobbies}
      initial={1}
      onPress={(value) => {ToastAndroid.show(value.toString(), 
ToastAndroid.SHORT)}}
      buttonSize={20}
      buttonOuterSize={40}
      selectedButtonColor={'green'}
      selectedLabelColor={'green'}
      labelStyle={{ fontSize: 15, }}
      disabled={false}
      formHorizontal={false}
    />
     <View style={styles.alternativeLayoutButtonContainer}>
     <Button
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        title="Proceed"
      />
      <Button
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        title="Go Back"
        color="#841584"
      />
    </View>
  </View>
  );
  }
  }
```

i would like the buy option in tennis to navigate to the payment page

Comment: Another thing: you dont need to bind if you are using arrow function `functionName= () => { }`

Comment: auticcat i did try props and also push but it dint work

Comment: Have you tried changing the function bind from constructor to the JSX instead?

So remove the 3 line of .bind(this) in constructor, then change the `onPress={this._onPressButton1}` to `onPress={this._onPressButton1.bind(this)}` see if that fixes your problem. _also, change the other _onPressButton too_

My guess is, with your call, the props itself is not sent to the function, thus when navigating through screens, the this.props.navigation is null and causes your error.

Comment: jakk's Team. it doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in case of react navigation you need to pass navigation to all those component which are not mentioned in you Stacknavigator

Firstly pass **this.props.navigation** to your components

Then use `this.props.navigation.navigate("Fifth")`

This should definitely work.

For more information you can go through the following link.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

Answer (score 0):

You missed props. Navigation object is passed to component as a props. So in tennis.js _onPressButton do this instead:

```
_onPressButton() {
   this.props.navigation.navigate("Fifth")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In tennis.js declare constructor(Props) to the Default class otherwise it won't the component wont get props object